# Is it possible to format Facebook notification text?

Tags: facebook

My application sends Facebook notifications to a user.
Is that possible to format the notification text with some html or fbml tags?

I've found out that `<a>` tag works just fine, but what about the others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only use a subset of HTML and FBML tags:

- HTML: `a, em, b, var, cite, dfn, i`
- FBML: `fb:name, fb:pronoun, fb:grouplink, fb:eventlink, fb:networklink, fb:user-table`

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Allowed_FBML_and_HTML_Tags#Notifications:_Allowed_Tags